# Azure ARM Template: DependsOn conditional statement

Tags: json, azure, azure-rm-template

Does anyone know if there is a way to put an inline conditional statement inside the **dependsOn** element?  I want to put a condition in that the resource will deploy on if either nestedTemplateA exists already OR if nestedTemplateB exists already.

Any help is appreciated!

```
  "dependsOn": [
    "[or(nestedTemplateA, nestedTemplateB)]"
  ],
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok, first of all, you can depend on existence of something (strictly speaking), you can only depend on resource being created successfully in the same (!!) template. so if your template has this structure:

```
resource1 - nested template
resource2 - nested template
resource3 - the one you are asking about
```

you just need to use this as dependsOn:

```
"dependsOn": [
    "resource1",
    "resource2"
]
```

but, as your question reads: "resource will deploy on if either nestedTemplateA exists already OR if nestedTemplateB exists already." its really hard for me to be sure I'm answering the right question. if this is not what you are asking about, can you please comment on this answer if you need more help (and, perhaps, rephrase your question). I'll edit this answer, cheers!

Comment: I see exactly what you are saying.   I do have multiple resources (resource1, resource2, resource3).  However, these resources are conditionals, so sometimes they are being deployed, sometimes not.  I was wondering if it is possible to use the dependsOn element as a conditional statement.  For example, if resource1 OR resource2 is deployed successfully, then create resource4.

Comment: basically just dependOn both, if they are skipped it wont crash. Also, if you need to skip it completely if they both are skipped, you need to use a condition. basically, just always depend on something you need to depend on, if its skipped, dependsOn doesnt break.

Comment: One more thing, In case the dependent resource doesn't exists, it will fail. In that case just add a function that returns an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

As of today, Azure has added support for the conditional dependsOn in [Define the order for deploying resources in ARM templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/define-resource-dependency#dependson)

This allows for the exact feature you are looking for. That is to say: You can simply add all conditional dependencies in the depondsOn array. Those dependencies evaluated as false will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I also could not explicitly find how to `or()` two dependencies within the `dependsOn`, however I think the plain/dumb approach below is fine too, though verbose,

```json
[
  {
    "name": "first", 
    "dependsOn": ["nestedTemplateA"],
    "do": "something"
  },
  {
    "name": "second", 
    "dependsOn": ["nestedTemplateB"],
    "do": "something"
  },
]
```

At least that is what I will do in my case. And it is at least not immediately obvious to me that the accepted answer, `"dependsOn": ["resource1", "resource2"]`,  is a logical or. Would love to find the documentation for this one day.